# DB2 large update performance is changing every time

Tags: db2

I have DB2 database version 11.5 running in linux. 
I am trying to measure speed of large updates - 1,000,000 rows each update.
Example:

```
UPDATE test.test1 SET col1= 'X'||col2||'A';
```

The problem is that the timing is **very different every time** I execute this update.
The timing varies from 2.2 sec to 7.8 sec.
What can I do to have consistent timing every time I run the update?

Additional info :

- The server that runs db2 does nothing else and I am the only session in the database, so it must be some db2 related behaviour.
- There are no indexes/constraints/triggers/FK's on the table
- The full structure of the table is:

```
    CREATE TABLE "TEST"."TEST1"  (
              "COL1" VARCHAR(128 OCTETS) NOT NULL , 
              "COL2" VARCHAR(128 OCTETS) NOT NULL , 
              "COL3" VARCHAR(128 OCTETS) NOT NULL )
    IN "USERSPACE1"  ORGANIZE BY ROW
```

Comment: Benchmarking requires detailed understanding of what you are measuring and which layers have which resources. If your I/O system is either virtualized or SAN based or both, then all bets are off because unless you have guaranteed non-varying response times from all layers (i.e. unlikely) then such variations are also guaranteed. Additionally it is unclear how your tablespace container(s) are configured, with without fs caching etc.

Comment: Are you updating different sets of rows with each update or the same set? The first time will be slower because data has to come from disk, and if you do the same stmt it will run faster the second time because the data is in memory.

Even if you are updating different sets of rows it is possible the first update brought rows you want in the second up[date into the bufferpool already.

Comment: The update statements updates the same dataset every time. How can I clear the memory cache? Is "FLUSH BUFFERPOOLS" sufficient for this purpose? The documentation claim it only "writes the dirty pages from all the local buffer pools for a particular database synchronously to disk" . So the question is whether it will clear clean pages also,

Answer (score 0):

This started off as a comment, but then seemed possibly worthy as an answer.  The performance of your DB2 instance doesn't only depend on the processes running within DB2 (such as triggers, other sessions, etc.).  It also depends on the other processes running on the OS which is running DB2.  The slight difference in performance you are seeing could easily be explained by demands being made on the OS from other processes besides DB2.  So, you might want to load your OS profiler and observe what happens during each update test in your DB2.

Comment: The server does nothing else except of my update. I have verified it by monitoring OS processes.